# Jquery click event not firing more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem wherein my JQuery click event only fires once. Basically, I have a small page set up with a button that reads Generate Buzzword. When you click on the button, the div "Oren-is" empties, and another div fades out. Then, a string from an array is appended to the emptied div. All of this works correctly with the code right now, but it only happens once.

I'm sure this is a very simple question: basically, how do I get this to happen more than once? After I click on "generate buzzword" the first time, everything fires correctly. However, I can't click it more than once!

Here is my code:

```
var $buzzwords = ["Oren Weingrod is object-oriented.", "Oren Weingrod is agile.", "Oren Weingrod is a human.", "Oren Weingrod is analytics driven.", "Oren Weingrod is dynamic!", "Oren Weingrod is lean", "Oren Weingrod is tele-commuting", "Oren Weingrod is integration testing"];

var $buzz = $('.generate-buzzword');
$(document).ready(function(){
var random = Math.floor((Math.random(8))*10);
alert(random);
$buzz.on("click", function(){
    $('#smalltext').remove();
    $('#oren-is').empty();
    $('#oren-is').append($buzzwords[random]);

    });
});
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<section id="oren">
            <p id="oren-is">Oren* Weingrod is not a pine tree. </p> 
            <a href="#" class="generate-buzzword"> Generate Buzzword </a> 
            <p id="smalltext">*Oren means pine tree in Hebrew.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: What happens when you do click? Have you tried adding `console.log()` calls to see if the "click" handler is being called?

Comment: You never update your random number, so you'll just redisplay the same message over and over again, so it won't look like it's working.

Comment: No worries, 95% of bugs are solved in under a second with a second set of eyes! =)  I also made a slight improvement in an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

To go along with my comment, change your code to actually generate a new radom number on each click:

```
$buzz.on("click", function(){
  var random = Math.floor((Math.random($buzzwords.length))*10);
  $('#smalltext').remove();
  $('#oren-is').empty();
  $('#oren-is').append($buzzwords[random]);

  });
});
```

I also made it so your magic number of '8' is now the length of your array of buzzwords, so when you add / remove, you don't have to update your code =)